# Power Spectral Density Plotting

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I am new to signal processing.I am analyzing the connection between the behavior of the Rossler model and its parameter c.
\begin{array}{ll}
\dot{x} = -y - z \\
\dot{y} = x + 0.2y  \\ \label{eq:UkladRosSP}
\dot{z} = 0.2 + z(x-c) 
\end{array}
I am trying to plot the Rossler's power spectral density but the results are not satsfying what I am expecting to get:
[image]

Instead I get the plots typical for discrete data set (example for a) c=2.6 ):
[image]

My code:

```
sol1 = NDSolve[{D[x[t], t] == -y[t] - z[t] , 
 D[y[t], t] == x[t] + 0.2*y[t], 
 D[z[t], t] == 0.2 + z[t] (x[t] - 2), x[0] == -1, y[0] == 0, 
 z[0] == 0 }, {z}, {t, 0, 7000}, MaxSteps -> Infinity][[1]];
g1 = ListLinePlot[
  Log[Abs[Fourier[
      Flatten[Table[Evaluate[z[t] /. sol1], {t, 0, 49, 0.001}]]]]^2], 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 50}, {-10, 10}}, ImageSize -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red}, Frame -> True, PlotLabel -> "Power Spectra", 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Red]]
```

How can I repair it?

Comment: Would you mind mentioning where you got the first image from?

Comment: The first image was taken from the : http://www.inet.ox.ac.uk/files/publications/farmer/powerspectral.pdf

Comment: It appears to me you are plotting only a small part of your data. Your seven thousand points span much more than that. You need to rescale your horizontal scale accordingly. Or just go with zdata = Table[z[t] /. sol1, {t, 0, 7000}]; zspect = Abs[Fourier[zdata]]^2; and then listplot zspect over all points.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe it's not the same , but they are almost identical! :)